# PHP Renaming files permission denied (Apache)

Tags: php, permissions, renaming

I'm stuck with a problem that I thought was easy. I have to temporarily rename a bunch of files. All folders are 0755, files are 0644. The server runs PHP 5.5 in CGI Mode. For test purposes I put both the script and the file to rename in the same folder:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chmod ($root."bla/_bla.php", 0777);
rename($root.'bla/_bla.php',$root.'bla.php');
chmod ($root."bla/bla.php", 0644);
```

But all I get is the "permission denied" error. Owner and group are for all files and folders the same. No luck even if I change folder and file to 0777. What exactly am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help. Hope, this isn't a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to chmod your php script. I meant this script not the one you want to rename. If you are using linux goto terminal and chmod. I think this would work

Comment: Sorry its chmod Not chmos. Which command u used? Have you tried  "chmod 777 'file.php' "

Comment: Thank you. The script is already set to 777 (for test purposes). I'm pretty sure that the chmod command I used is correct (see my first post).